# std::is_constant_evaluated behavior for const variables

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, if-constexpr

GCC9 already implements `std::is_constant_evaluated`. I played a little bit with it, and I realized it is somewhat tricky. Here’s my test:

```
constexpr int Fn1()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}

constexpr int Fn2()
{
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
  constexpr int test1 = Fn1(); // Evaluates to 0
  int test2 = Fn1();           // Evaluates to 0
  int const test3 = Fn1();     // Evaluates to 0

  constexpr int test4 = Fn2(); // Evaluates to 0
  int test5 = Fn2();           // Evaluates to 1
  int const test6 = Fn2();     // Evaluates to 0
}
```

According to these results, I extracted the following conclusions:

- `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())` always evaluates the
  `true` branch. Therefore, it makes no sense to use this construct.
- If the compiler evaluates a variable at compile time,
  `std::is_constant_evaluated())` is `true`, no matter whether that
  variable is explicitly annotated `constexpr` or not.

Am I right?

Comment: What headers and compiler options have you used for this?

Comment: @P.W the header `<type_traits>` and the compiler option `-std=c++2a`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`if constexpr` requires a constant expression for a condition. So `is_constant_evaluated` is of course always going to be true in such a context.

It's meant for a regular `if`. The purpose is to not go into a code path that is illegal in a `constexpr` function when evaluated in a constant expression. But to let it execute in runtime. It's not there to eliminate those code paths from the function altogether.

Comment: there can be code paths in a `constexpr` function that cannot be evaluated at compile-time? There is so much I still have to learn :)

Comment: @user463035818 `constexpr` means "there exist arguments to this function that may allow compile-time evaluation". It does not mean "this function will always be evaluated at compile-time". This means e.g. `std::abs` can be `constexpr`: When called with `constexpr` arguments it can be evaluated at compile-time, but it can still be used as normal at runtime.

Comment: @MaxLanghof but can you actually implement a `constexpr` function with logic that can never be executed at compile time? I think that's what **user463035818** meant. I am surprised too. The thing for function template is obvoisly different. Example which I think is relevant - you can never have a `constexpr` function that will return `std::string`, no matter where and how you'd call it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof ah thanks, got it. In case you pass non compile time arguments it makes little sense to require that the function can be evaluated at compile time

Comment: I would have expected the compiler to optimize away the constant evaluation code path when generating the runtime version of the function, which is something likely to happen anyway. So `if constexpr` made sense to me.

Comment: @metalfox - I understand. It's a bit counter intuitive at first. Point is. The function tells you *when* something is evaluated. So if you put it in a context that can only be evaluated at a specific time..

Answer (score 18):

Here's how I think about this, maybe you'll find this helpful... maybe not. Note that I think writing `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())` will be a really common error, and it's an easy trap to fall into. But hopefully compilers will just diagnose that case. Submitted [91428](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91428), which is fixed for gcc 10.1.

---

We essentially have two different rules for code - the typical rules for normal runtime code, and the restrictions for constant expressions that are for `constexpr` programming. Those are the expr.const restrictions: no UB, no `reinterpret_cast`, etc. Those restrictions keep decreasing from language standard to language standard, which is great.

Basically, control flow (from a code path perspective) alternates between being in the "full runtime" mode and the `constexpr` mode. Once we enter the `constexpr` mode (whether by initializing a `constexpr` object or evaluating a template parameter or ...), we stay there until we're done... and then we're back to full runtime mode.

What `is_constant_evaluated()` does is simply: Am I in constexpr mode? It tells you if you're on a context that requires constant expressions.

In that view, let's look at `if constexpr (is_constant_evaluated())`. Regardless of what state we used to be in, `if constexpr` requires a constant expression as its initialized so this lifts us into constexpr mode if we weren't there already. Hence, `is_constant_evaluated()` is just true - unconditionally.

However, for `if (is_constant_evaluated())`, a simple `if` doesn't change our state between runtime and constexpr. So the value here depends on the context it was called from. Initializing `test4` puts us onto constexpr mode because it's a constexpr object. For the duration of its initialization, we follow the constant expression rules... so `is_constant_evaluated()`is true. But once we're done, we're back to runtime rules... so in the initialization of `test5`, `is_constant_evaluated()` is false. (And then `test6` is an unfortunate language special case - you can use constant integral variables as constant expressions, so we treat their initialization the same way for these purposes.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm fine with the `test6` case. It is quite logical to behave that way. I find the `if constexpr` case more counter-intuitive.

Comment: @metalfox I suspect that will be a very common misunderstanding. I will add a note to the answer to that effect

Comment: GCC 10+ will warn about the `if constexpr` case: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2019-08/msg01841.html

Comment: The case with constant integers is even weirder, since they *can* be constant expressions, but needn’t be.  (Of course, any dynamic initialization can be done statically, but that’s usually unobservable.)

Comment: GCC 91428 says that is_constant_evaluated is probably going to be removed. What will it be replaced by?

Comment: @Johannes It's not getting removed.