# is_constant_evaluated() should produce constexpr variables?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

I have read the `std::is_constant_evaluated()` definition, but I still not sure why (1) is not working with the **latest GCC**: `error: 'x' is not a constant expression`

```
template<auto v>
struct s
{};

constexpr void f(int x)
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
        // constexpr int z=x; (1)
        // s<x> a; (2)
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f(4);
    //f(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

1. By the standard, should that work?
2. Or just the GCC implementation is buggy?
3. Somehow can I achieve the expected behavior? Which is basically:

**With branching on `std::is_constant_evaluated()`**

- **if it is true: the code can use variables as constexpr (like (2))**
- **if it is false: the code use variables as non-constexpr**

**UPDATE**

Can I 'transport' the constexpr-essiveness information into a function? Basically to decide in `f()` that it was call with `constexpr` x or not.

**UPDATE**
A more complex example about what I would like to achieve: this sample should stringify the parameter in compile time if possible.

```
template<auto v>
struct dummy_stringify
{
    static constexpr auto str=v==4 ? "4" : "31"; // this is just an example; imagine here a much more complex logic
};

constexpr void f(int x)
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
        std::puts("A compile time calculation:");
        //std::puts(dummy_stringify<x>::str);
    } else
    {
        std::cout<<"A runtime calculation:"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f(4);
    f(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251530/stdis-constant-evaluated-behavior

Comment: Please elaborate more on the expected behavior and *why* you want to achieve it. There may be another alternative altogether.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have added a more complex example. I have a solution: if I would wrap the param `f(wrap<4>);`, I would be able to overload the f() on that wrap type... But I would like to unify the behavior in one function, if possible

Comment: Did you mean to use `if constexpr`?

Comment: @BalázsÁrva - I'm afraid C++ doesn't have the means to unify it yet, to my knowledge.

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())` is always true. I think basically meaningless to use it. Or `if constexpr ()` what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

I have found a solution with a little helper class (of course one can use `std::integral_constant`)

```
template<auto val_>
struct val
{
    static constexpr auto value=val_;
};

template<auto v>
struct dummy_stringify
{
    static constexpr auto str=v==4 ? "4" : "31"; // this is just an example; imagine here a much more complex logic
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
constexpr void f(T x)
{
    if constexpr(requires{ T::value; })
    {
        std::puts("A compile time calculation:");
        std::puts(dummy_stringify<T::value>::str);
    } else
    {
        std::cout<<"A runtime calculation:"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f(val<4>{});
    f(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

It can be improved with a `template<char...> auto operator""_v();` to `f(4_v)`

Answer (score 7):

`x` is not a constant expression, no matter how `f` itself is evaluated. That's a regular `if` right there (how `is_constant_evaluated` is meant to be used). It's not a discarded branch, so it has to contain well-formed code even when `f` is *not* constant evaluated. When `x` won't be a constant expression the function will still contain that (unexecuted) branch, and it will attempt to use `x` where a constant expression is required. That's plain ill-formed.

GCC is very much correct not to accept it.

Comment: Thank you, I added an update based on your answer. But as I see, you answer would be for that question definitelly NO. Am I right?

Comment: @BalázsÁrva - As far as I can see. But it's possible I don't understand your goal enough to say otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental issue here is that, even with a `constexpr` (or even `consteval`) function being called during constant evaluation (and under an `is_constant_evaluated` check), there is still only **one** function shared among all argument values.  You therefore can’t **ever** use a function parameter as a constant expression (even if the *call* with that parameter is a constant expression).  If you want a constant-expression parameter, it has to be a **template** parameter.