# C++20. is_constant_evaluated() vs if constexpr

Tags: c++, c++20

Here is example from cppreference:

```
constexpr double power(double b, int x)
{
if (std::is_constant_evaluated() && !(b == 0.0 && x < 0)) {
    // A constant-evaluation context: Use a constexpr-friendly algorithm.
    if (x == 0)
        return 1.0;
    double r = 1.0, p = x > 0 ? b : 1.0 / b;
    auto u = unsigned(x > 0 ? x : -x);
    while (u != 0) {
        if (u & 1) r *= p;
        u /= 2;
        p *= p;
    }
    return r;
} else {
    // Let the code generator figure it out.
    return std::pow(b, double(x));
}
}
```

As you can see `std::is_constant_evaluated()`. My question is why can't we use `if constexpr` here to check if the function call occurs within a constant-evaluated context?

Comment: Are you asking why `if constexpr` can't be used instead of `if` here?

Comment: yes. it is exactly what I'm trying to understand

Comment: @rudolfninja: What do you think that condition is doing? And what would, in your mind, an equivalent `if constexpr` condition would look like?

Comment: Related question: [std::is\_constant\_evaluated behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251530/stdis-constant-evaluated-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

The question which `is_constant_evaluated()` is asking is exactly spelled out in its name: "is this expression being evaluated within constant expression evaluation?" A function declared `constexpr` may or may not be executed as part of constant expression evaluation. So calling that function within such a context may return different values depending on how the implementation calls it.

However, the condition of `if constexpr` *must be* a constant expression, regardless of what function it happens to be in. And therefore, executing `is_constant_evaluated()` within `if constexpr`'s condition will always yield `true`.

You cannot use `is_constant_evaluated` with `if constexpr`'s condition or any other explicitly `constexpr` context. Well, you can, but it probably won't return the result that you're actually interested in.

What this code is ultimately doing is creating two versions of the function: one which is optimized for runtime execution and the other which is optimized for compile-time execution. That requires having a condition that tests which version needs to be called.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of `std::is_constant_evaluated` is to be able to dispatch between run time and compile time in your if statement.

If you were to use `if constexpr`, then you would already be in a constant expression and the condition will always be true.

Instead you use a regular `if` and *if* you are in a constant expression you'll get the if part at compile time and if not you'll get the else part at run time.

Answer (score 0):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) already answers your question:

> When directly used as the condition of `static_assert` declaration or `constexpr if` statement, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` always returns `true`.