# C++20, is there a constexpr alternative to `std::is_constant_evaluated()`?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I understand that `std::is_constant_evaluated` [cannot be properly used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457604/c20-is-constant-evaluated-vs-if-constexpr) in an `if constexpr` call.

Is there any similar way of distinguishing between `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` paths within a function, but at compile-time? I often find myself desiring this pattern:

```
constexpr auto MyFunc()
{
   if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())
   {
      return Type();
   }
   else{
      return OtherType();
   }
}
```

However, since this isn't a `constexpr` conditional, this function isn't able to compile with different auto-deducted return types. My solution so far has been to simply make differently named `constexpr` versions of the function whenever I run into this pattern, but I'm really hoping for a less clunky approach.

Comment: That's what [`if consteval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213012/what-is-if-consteval-needed-for) will do in C++23.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was just reading that proposal. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality in c++10?

Comment: There's not enough info on `if consteval`. I am not sure of it can affect the return type of its function. Both `if` and `else` - in case `else` exists - need compound statements. In C++20, the only tool is what OP suggets; and it is implmented by compiler magic.

Comment: [GCC says "inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'Type' and then 'OtherType'"](https://godbolt.org/z/3PvPE8xTa) -- Mind if I ask why you need this? I can't really come up with a sensible use case for this.

Comment: My return type in the non-constexpr case uses pointers to non-statically allocated memory, so in the constexpr case, I just copy all of that data (using a different type) since it's not a runtime cost. It'd be nice if I could keep all of that logic contained within a single function.